# Gmail show Moved Permanently in mail detail

Tags: php, gmail, amazon-ses

I send an email by php code.
I use api `Aws\Ses\SesClient` to send email.

This is my code:

```php
function sendOrderInfoToCustomer($sTo){
    $ch = curl_init($this->sMainUrl."/content_email_order_info.php?orderID=".$this->iOrderID);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $sContentOrderInfo = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $sSubject = $this->oPublicFunction->getSiteName()." [".$this->oPublicFunction->parseFormatTime("d/m/Y H:i A",time())."]";
    $this->oPublicFunction->sendMailAWS($sTo,$sSubject,$sContentOrderInfo);
}

function sendMailAWS($sTo,$sSubject,$sBody){
        global $aws_access_key, $aws_secret_access_key, $aws_from;
        $client = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory(array(
            'version'=> 'latest',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => array(
                'key'    => $aws_access_key,
                'secret' => $aws_secret_access_key
            )
        ));
        $request = array();
        $request['Source'] = $aws_from;
        $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array($sTo);
        $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = $sSubject;
        $request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $sBody;

        try {
            $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
            $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
            //echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ");
            echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
        }
    }
```

Send mail is success. But I check mail on gmail I see email is not good.

[image: Gmail detail]

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a result of email, it's actually the content that your CURL is getting from your own server when building the message body. You probably just have to tell curl to follow redirects:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

You may have a more serious problem here, however. Your app (generally) shouldn't be using web requests to itself. The email content should be created via an internal method call that renders the order template, and *not* by calling a web page. Here, it appears that you've opened the order detail page to the entire web. I.e., anybody on the web can hit `content_email_order_info.php?orderID=123` and get the details for any order because there's no authentication going on there. This could be a very serious security breach.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'll review and try to fix it.